# Windows 7 unresponsive after hibernate

Tags: windows-7

The last few days, when I get Windows out of hibernate, Windows itself gets unresponsive. I can use any of my programs that were already opened before hibernating, but the window functions (closing, changing the size etc) aren't reacting. I can't open any new programs, except for the Task Manager.

Also, I don't get an Internet connection. When I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>, I get either a black screen, or the regular background. Then it hangs and after a while shows me a message that Windows failed starting up that "thing"(don't know what it's called in English, something with safety, etc).

I have Windows 7 Ultimate installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would disable hibernation, delete c:\hiberfil.sys, then reenable it. Hiberfil.sys is a hidden file, you will need to enable viewing of hidden files by opening Computer, hitting the ALT key, and going to Tools>Folder Options>View and click "Show hidden files, folder, and drives". You may also want to uncheck "Hide protected operating system files".

This is how to disable and reenable hibernation:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/819-hibernate-enable-disable.html

Have you updated your graphics driver? If that does not work, I would update my BIOS too.

I also found an interesting solution on the Internet: Is your computer using readyboost, and if so, how is the drive formatted? If so, make sure that it is formatted in NTFS.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/black-screen-after-hibernation-with-readyboost-sd/1d679969-7888-47c5-b748-6ddebcc2ad76

I would also look at this:

http://www.prevx.com/blog/140/Black-Screen-woes-could-affect-millions-on-Windows--Vista-and-XP.html (this has been updated to include Windows 7).

Comment: Simon says that hibernate was working, then stopped. It's hard to explain how that could be a BIOS issue, unless he upgraded the BIOS already and didn't mention it.

Comment: I'll try that :) will keep you updated.
@CarlF: it is possible my hibernate file was corrupted or something, re-enabling might fix this.

Comment: CarlF It is not my first choice, but this is a very common issue, and one of the standard steps is to update the BIOS. There could be come new update that needs new BIOS code...It may do nothing, but it is still a good idea since it can rule something relatively simple out.